# mcrypt_decrypt() not returning correct data

Tags: php, security, encryption, base64, mcrypt

I will just reference the code here, but the full code can be found on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tyfW67D7).

*I am using `POST` requests to send data to and from the encryption server (I am doing encryption work on my 2nd server, for added security), so that is why everything is initially received as a `$_POST` variable.*

So, basically what is happening is I am encrypting some data using the encryption script (which can be found on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/tyfW67D7)), then taking the encrypted data from that and trying to decrypt it using the same method. I am using `mcrypt_decrypt()` to decrypt the data. I have done some experimenting with it, and when I try to print the data that `base64_decode()` returns, I get no value. I think this may have something to do with the error, but I am getting random ASCII characters as a result, for example, this is a result I obtained recently:

> ]A}���/7Q�Ț��/����&�����OO�

The initialisation vector is stored with the original data, and I am using `explode()` to separate it, the format is like this: `"IV:Encrypted String"`.

PHP is not throwing any errors when I run this, and I have based this off the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php).

The encryption process works perfectly and the decryption script is able to return the encrypted text before it is decoded and decrypted, so the data is reaching the server find.

*if you need any more info, please ask in comments, I would be happy to provide it for you!* :)

Comment: Hey, maybe use https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption instead of that mcrypt code?

Comment: Standard comment about not using `mcrypt_*` functions because they are deprecated and don't use PKCS7 padding etc.

Comment: @Luke Park oh are they deprecated, I never knew!

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Comment: @DibDibs Open-source is rarely deprecated, it is just abandoned waiting for the next Google search to present it fresh as if it is the equal to all others. Heck even Microsoft has a current encryption example code using DES which should not have been used for the last decade!

Answer (score 0):

Is the data stored in a database? If so, you might want to take a look at your collation settings. 
The `mcrypt_encrypt` method might generate characters that cannot be stored in your database's default coallition, which would explain the random characters.

Comment: No it is not, but it will be, thanks for the heads up, will escaping the string fix this when i do store it in a database?